# Moving a paragraph element next to another paragraph element

Tags: html, css, forms

Sounds easy and it probably is. [Here is a form I am currently working on](https://codepen.io/CptMacaroni/pen/qYEzLe) and I'd like to place the `lastName` directly next to the `firstName`.

Here is what I have.

```css
body {
  background: #384047;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3em 2em 2em;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  border-radius: none;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  position: relative;
}

#moreInfo {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Drop-down menu's */

#dropDown1 {
  width: 350px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#dropDown2 {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  color: grey;
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
  color: #333;
}

input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
}

#firstName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#lastName {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#eMail {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#telephone {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#address {
  background: f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* buttons */

#submitMore {
  background: #2080df;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#applyNow {
  background: #40bf80;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 2em 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #68b25b;
}

#para1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: #dadada;
  padding: ;
}

#OReo {
  text-align: center;
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 1em;
}



.alert {
  display: none;
  font-size: .5em;
}



/*      Validation Form Response      */

.error {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: .5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">

    <!-- drop-down -->
    <h1 id="moreInfo">Request More Information</h1>

    <p>
      <label for="degreeType">What degree type would you like?*</label>
      <select id="dropDown1" name="dropDown1">
    <option id="dropDown1" selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
  </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label for="selectDegree">What would you like to study?*<label>
      <select id="dropDown2" name="dropDown2">
    <option selected="selected">Select degree type above</option>
    <option value="gen2">Example 1</option>
    <option value="gen3">Example 2</option>
    <option value="gen4">Example 3</option>
</select>
  </p>
        <div class="firstNlast">
        <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name*<label>
        <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="firstName">
          <span class="left"></span>
        </p>
          
          <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name*<label>
        <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="lastName">
          
        </p>
            </div>
          
          <p>
        <label for="eMail">Email*<label>
        <input id="eMail" name="eMail" type="text">
          <span class="left"></span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="telephone">Telephone*<label>
        <input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text">
          <span class="right"></span>
        </p>
         
          <p>
        <label for="address">Address*<label>
        <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
        <span class="left"></span>
        </p>
          
          <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Tell Me More" id="submitMore">
          </p>
          <p id="para1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices pulvinar scelerisque. Curabitur auctor faucibus est, ut lobortis ante tempus sit amet. Phasellus fermentum aliquet turpis, at tempus tortor euismod nec. Pellentesque ligula nunc, maximus et venenatis ac, tempor vel sem.
       </p>
          <h1 id="OReo">----------  OR  -------------</h1>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply Now" id="applyNow">
          <form action="#" method="post">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>Successfully submitted!</strong> The form is valid.
      </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
.firstNlast p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is embarrassing that I missed this. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: When i added this my `firstName` and `lastName` are now unresponsive. I cannot place text in them.

Comment: You have to clear the float again. add <div style="clear: both;"></div> after the last p element

Comment: Brilliant! Once last adjustment. the text above my email form `Email` has moved over to the right. Should i use the inline method?

Comment: there is an empty p tag after your clear: both, just remove it

Comment: Wow! Why does it do that exactly?